# How can I check if leap year in AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript

The following code is to check if it's a leap year once the program detects the current month is February.

The "if" code seems quite redundant.

```
set MM to month of (current date) as number
if (MM = 2) then

    set YY to year of (current date)
    if (YY mod 400 = 0) then
        set Prefix to Gregorian_Leap
    else if (YY mod 100 = 0) then
        set Prefix to Gregorian_28
    else if (YY mod 4 = 0) then
        set Prefix to Gregorian_Leap
    else
        set Prefix to Gregorian_28
    end if

else if (MM = 4 or MM = 6 or MM = 9 or MM = 11) then
    set Prefix to Gregorian_30
else
    set Prefix to Gregorian_31
end if
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach would be to ask for the month of February 29. In a non-leap year, it should return 'March'.

```
month of date "2/29/2018"
```

This shows the approach but as pointed out in the comments, the above is automatically compiled into a long date.

To address this and to also provide flexibility as to the year, this will return ‘February’ in a leap year, and ‘March’ otherwise.

```
month of date ("2/29/" & (year of (current date) as text))
```

-> March

Incorporating the question code, it could look like this. I ordered it this way so as to bail out of the elses earlier for more months.

```
set g31 to {1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12}
set g30 to {4, 6, 9, 11}

set MM to month of (current date) as integer

if g31 contains MM then
    set Prefix to "Gregorian_31"
else
    if g30 contains MM then
        set Prefix to "Gregorian_30"
    else
        if month of date ("2/29/" & (year of (current date))) as integer = 2 then
            set Prefix to "Gregorian_Leap"
        else
            set Prefix to "Gregorian_28"
        end if
    end if
end if
```

Comment: Just to be clear, one cannot just use `month of date "2/29/2018"`, **as is**, because when the _code_ is compiled it is automatically converted to e.g. `month of date "Thursday, March 1, 2018 at 12:00:00 AM"` but the second line of code can be wrapped in a `if` _statement_ to make the determination and act accordingly. It's a novel approach and I would have upvoted had you shown a practical _code_ example of it's use, e.g.: `if (month of date ("2/29/" & ((year of (current date)) as text)) as text) contains "February" then` ... `-- # It's a leap year, add you leap year code here:` ... `end if`.

Comment: Note that the ... in the comment above represents a _newline_, as comments do not show them when pasting a _code block_ into a comment.

Comment: Fair comment. The compile effect is annoying. It’s probably more elaborate than the question asked, but as suggested, I fleshed out the answer to also deal specifically with the scenario. Thanks.

Comment: Nice alternative method to that of the OP. +1 BTW You have an extra set of `()` in `if month of date ("2/29/" & ((year of (current date)))) as integer = 2 then`

Comment: Thanks. I think that while working through options, I kept adding and removing bits and pieces, and ended up leaving the parentheses in there. Lucky I'm not a surgeon. I don't suppose Apple will ever do anything about it, but it would be nice if they developed the date/time functions some more.